# transition background of pseudo element

Tags: css

I have a pseudo element which has a border radius of 50% and a background color when I hover on it, so a circle will be displayed when I do the hover.

I want to add a transition so the circle looks like it grows when I hover (like when you hover the star icon on gmail), but I can't figure out how to do it.

This is what I tried :

```css
.container {
  position        : relative;
  height          : 100px;
  width           : 300px;
  padding         : 24px;
  background      : #fff;
  display         : flex;
  flex-direction  : column;
  justify-content : space-between;
  box-sizing      : border-box;
  color           : black;
  list-style      : none;
  border          : 2px solid black;
  }
input[type="checkbox"] {
  height     : 40px;
  width      : 40px;
  position   : absolute;
  top        : 12px;
  right      : 12px;
  margin     : auto;
  appearance : none;
  outline    : none;
  cursor     : pointer;
  opacity    : 1;
  border     : none;
  }
input[type="checkbox"]::after {
  content                    : url("https://svgshare.com/i/Qo7.svg");
  position                   : absolute;
  top                        : 0;
  left                       : 0;
  border-radius              : 50%;
  margin                     : auto;
  width                      : 100%;
  height                     : 100%;
  pointer-events             : none;
  display                    : flex;
  justify-content            : center;
  align-items                : center;
  z-index                    : 2;
  transition-duration        : 1s;
  transition-timing-function : cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-property        : background;
  background-size            : 40%;
  background-position        : center;
  }
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  content             : url("https://svgshare.com/i/Qmp.svg");
  } 
input[type="checkbox"]:hover:after {
  background      : linear-gradient(to bottom, #D9DEEA 0%, #D9DEEA 100%) no-repeat;
  background-size : 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

And I have another issue is that the star is not properly centered inside the cicrle.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize your code and do everything using background. Your SVG was not perfectly centered because the SVG itself has the start that is not in the center.

```css
svg {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="19"><path d="M9.333 13.2c.134 0 .267 0 .4.133l3.734 2.8L12 11.467c-.133-.267 0-.534.267-.667L16 7.867h-4.667c-.266 0-.533-.134-.666-.534l-1.334-4.4-1.466 4.534c0 .266-.267.4-.534.4H2.667L6.4 10.8c.267.133.4.4.267.667L5.2 16.133l3.733-2.8c.134-.133.267-.133.4-.133m5.334 5.467c-.134 0-.267 0-.4-.134l-4.934-3.866L4.4 18.4a.85.85 0 01-.8 0c-.267-.133-.4-.533-.267-.8L5.2 11.467.267 7.733C0 7.6 0 7.333 0 7.067c.133-.267.4-.4.667-.4H6.8L8.667.533C8.8 0 9.733 0 10 .533l1.867 6.134H18c.267 0 .533.133.667.4.133.266 0 .533-.267.8l-4.933 3.866 1.866 6.134c.134.266 0 .533-.266.8-.134-.134-.267 0-.4 0" fill="#2D75FF" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg>
```

Either change the SVG or consider some offset to rectify the position:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 12px;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background:
    var(--img,url("https://svgshare.com/i/Qo7.svg")) calc(50% + 1px) 50% /60% 60%,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,#D9DEEA 99%,transparent) center/ var(--s,0px 0px);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:0.5s;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:hover {
    --s:100% 100%;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  --img: url("https://svgshare.com/i/Qmp.svg");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" >

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine on chrome, but it doesn't really work on IE11 :(

Comment: @RenaudisNotBillGates css variables aren't support in IE, you need to write the code without CSS variables