# Any workaround for the CSS var?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

This is a followup for a solved question :

[transition background of pseudo element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64491853/transition-background-of-pseudo-element)

The idea is to add a transition to the background color which appears when we do a hover, this following code works on IE11, but without the transition:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  appearance: none;
}


 input[type=checkbox] + label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label::before {
  content: url("https://svgshare.com/i/Qo7.svg");
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
 input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
  content: url("https://svgshare.com/i/Qmp.svg");
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
 input[type=checkbox]:hover + label:before {
  background: #D9DEEA;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"/>
<label for="checkbox1"></label>
```

However, this code doesn't work on IE11, since it doesn't support `var`:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  appearance: none;
}


 input[type=checkbox] + label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label::before {
  content: url("https://svgshare.com/i/Qo7.svg");
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-side,#D9DEEA 99%,transparent) center/ var(--s,0px 0px);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:0.5s;
}
 input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
  content: url("https://svgshare.com/i/Qmp.svg");
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
 input[type=checkbox]:hover + label:before {
  --s:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"/>
<label for="checkbox1"></label>
```

I have updated the code from the solution of my previous question, so it can work with IE11, but I couldn't figure out how to do a workaround for `var` in IE11.

## Edit

Thanks to @Temani Afif answer, I managed to do the transition without the `var` and using checkbox with input (since pseudo element are not meant to be used on replaced elements such as form elements (inputs)):

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  appearance: none;
}


 input[type=checkbox] + label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label::before {
  content: url("https://svgshare.com/i/Qo7.svg");
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-side,#D9DEEA 99%,transparent) center/ 0px 0px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:0.5s;
}
 input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
  content: url("https://svgshare.com/i/Qmp.svg");
  border: none;
}
 input[type=checkbox]:hover + label:before {
  background-size: 40px 40px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"/>
<label for="checkbox1"></label>
```

But in IE11 the background just appears instantly without the transition.

Comment: apart from the variables, the `appearance` property isn't supported by IE11 - I wonder that you state that the first version works in IE11?

Comment: @Johannes yes exactly

Comment: Genuine question meant in good faith: why are you looking to support IE11? It's 7 years old, Microsoft won't be supporting it for much longer, it has a tiny market share worldwide and not only has it been superseded by Edge but Edge has been superseded by Edge (Blink). Microsoft describes IE11 as a ["compatibility solution" which you shouldn't use](https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-security-chief-ie-is-not-a-browser-so-stop-using-it-as-your-default/). Others agree with Microsoft: https://css-tricks.com/a-business-case-for-dropping-internet-explorer/

Comment: background-size does not support transition in genuine IE11, a work around can be shadow : https://jsbin.com/sufaguquci/1/edit?html,css,output (jsbin runs in IE11)

Comment: @Rounin well tell that to our testers, they even test the app in IE11 mobile which as far as I know, no one use it.

Comment: I sympathise, @RenaudisNotBillGates. Maybe you could suggest they also run some tests on Netscape Navigator 2 or NCSA Mosaic (?)

Comment: It appears instantly without the transition in IE 11 because transition on pseudo elements is not supported by IE. `transition:0.5s` in `input[type=checkbox] + label::before ` will not work in IE 11. You can check the compatibility for [Animation and transition support of ::before (:before)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No CSS variables solution

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 12px;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background:
    url("https://svgshare.com/i/Qo7.svg") calc(50% + 1px) 50% /60% 60%,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,#D9DEEA 99%,transparent) center/ 0px 0px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:0.5s;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:hover {
    background-size:
     60% 60%,
     100% 100%;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-image:
    url("https://svgshare.com/i/Qmp.svg"),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,#D9DEEA 99%,transparent);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" >

</div>
```

Comment: Could you please check the edit i did to my post at the bottom